# When I scroll my UIScrollView, animations that are connected to a timer and animate views inside of the scrollview, suddenly stop ticking

Tags: swift, timer, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView containing views, which are connected to timers that call a function every x seconds. Everything works perfectly, until I start scrolling the scroll view, upon which the timers stop ticking, meaning that the animations stop happening. I do not know if this is clear enough, but I will show you some code below to try to clarify.

```
@objc func lowBeatingAnimation(){
        for i in lowWindow{
            let List = i as? [Any] ?? []
            let View = List[0] as! UIView
            let width = List[1] as! NSLayoutConstraint
            let height = List[2] as! NSLayoutConstraint
            let label = List[3] as! UILabel
            
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                View.layer.shadowRadius = 50
                width.constant += -20
                height.constant += -20
                label.alpha = 0.65
                View.layer.cornerRadius += -10
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: { finished in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    View.layer.shadowRadius = 10
                    width.constant += 20
                    View.layer.cornerRadius += 10
                    label.alpha = 0.85
                    height.constant += 20
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }, completion: { finished in
                
                })
            })
        }
    }
```

That is the function I call every second. lowWindow is an array, consisting of arrays with the following format: [UIView, NSLayoutConstraint (belonging to the first element in the list), NSLayoutConstraint (also belonging to the first element in the list), UILabel]

The first element in lowWindow is a UIView, which is a subview of the scroll view, which causes the animation to stop whenever it gets scrolled.

I think the issue can be boiled down to the following question, although I am not entirely sure: Why does an external timer stop working whenever the position of the scrollview gets edited?

I have also tried different things in terms of whether the views that get animated are direct subviews of the scrollview, or if they are subviews of a subview of the scrollview. Nothing works so far. If you have any ideas on how to solve this and would like to share it, that would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the timers to Runloop.

```
RunLoop.main.add(lowTimer, forMode: .common)
RunLoop.main.add(mediumTimer, forMode: .common)
RunLoop.main.add(highTimer, forMode: .common)
```

Comment: There are multiple modes that the RunLoop will run in.  During scrolling, it limits what is processed to make sure that the scrolling is as smooth as possible.  Things in the default mode are not processed during these times.  The common mode as you use above includes default and eventTracking, so it will be processed.